# ERROR in The target entry-point "ngx-cookie-service" has missing dependencies: in Angular 10.1.2

Tags: angular, ngx-cookie-service

I am making a change from local storage to ngx-cookie-service but when running the platform I get the error:
ERROR in The target entry-point "ngx-cookie-service" has missing dependencies:

- @ angular / core
- @ angular / common

My app.module.ts

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ CookieService ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

CookieService

```
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {

  private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  private user: Observable<User>;
  
  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {
    this.userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(JSON.parse(this.cookieService.get('USER')));
    this.user = this.userSubject.asObservable();
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any sample code that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 0):

Found a possible solution in this thread here.

https://github.com/salemdar/ngx-cookie/issues/106#issuecomment-598242367

I had the same issue and updated the **ngx-cookie-service** package from my current version **12.0.0** to **14.0.0**. Seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).